# Looking for which NoSQL db appropriate in our case

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, redis, tracking

We have a tracking system running in PHP + MySQL.
We receive about 8 to 10 millions entries per day which represent an average of about 100 insertions per seconds on 3 tables linked with a clickid key.
In parallel we can select on those tables to search for a clickid or update one after conversion etc...
We are looking for a better solution to be able to use the backoffice and get statistics in realtime because right now it takes about 150 seconds to display a result.
We use cronjobs to fill out a stats table and work with it, which allow us to get very quick result, but this cronjob runs twice per hour so we ar far away from real time stats...

So, we are thinking to switch to a NoSQL solution but we are not sure which nosql db will be the most adapted to our specific case?
We should be able to fiter and retrieve statistics by about 8 different keys like campaignid, publisherid, advertiserid, date, ...

We were thinking to test Mongodb and Redis, which one do you think will be the most appropriate? And why, in your opinion? We do have now about 500.000.000 entries we should insert as documents, and every seconds about 100 documents will be inserted... So it will increase quiet fast and we ll need to keep the data.
What do you think will be the time to display result with this quantity of data?

Also, do you think it is better to split in different Collections or better to keep everything in a single big Collection?

Comment: SO does not tend to do recommendations due to their subjective and opinionated content and views. They tend to create prolonged and unproductive prolonged debate normally resulting in nothing more than a flame war

Answer (score 1):

I dont have extensive experience with Redis but I could tell you something about MongoDB.

The NOSQL movement is more about scalability. So there would be very limited options if you want to keep it in one collection. Most of the NOSQL DB would break that up into sharded replica sets. You can read about it [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding/) .If you are planning on MongoDB, the writes could be quick, since its sharded and replicated. If you dont mind data being a bit stale(depending upon the latency between the primary and the secondary in the shard), MongoDB can be a good alternative.

Typically, you could write to the primary and read from the secondary, as opposed to your current scenario, where I guess everything happens on one DB. This should be significant performance boost for your ops, but exactly how much would depend on the details.

Comment: Thank you Scrooj for this answer.

Comment: Sorry mistake with the comment unfinished. Concerning MongoDB, with the amount of documents we would have, do you think it can run on a single machine for the moment? Also, how do you recommend the structure for the indexes? Is there better few single index or compound indexes?

Comment: Technically speaking you can run it on a single machine..but that is not the standard way of doing it.Read about it at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-architectures-production/ ..Going by these recommendations you need to have an incredibly powerful machine to meet your needs..

Answer (score 0):

You can actually either, [both](http://blog.mongohq.com/redis-mongodb-and-the-power-of-incremency/) or neither :) I still don't understand what your requirements are, and most importantly in terms of your current data volume and expected growth pattern, nor what you want to get out of it apart from getting statistic in real time. I also didn't quite get if you're planning to replace the MySQL entirely or whether you're going to build on top/beside it.

I definitely agree that 150s is not an acceptable response time for your dashboard, but before diving head on into a forklift operation, I suggest that maybe you should consider a simpler approach like just keeping your realtime statistics counters in a suitable datastore (e.g. Redis ;)).